# CEF - how to get a variable from JS to С++

Tags: javascript, c++, chromium-embedded

Please help me, I've been suffering for two weeks, I can't understand if it's possible in CEF to get the value of a variable from the JS code to a C++ variable?

For example:

I am executing js code in a browser window using the method CefFrame::ExecuteJavaScript:

```
(*frame).GetMainFrame()).ExecuteJavaScript("const elem = document.getElementsByClassName("my_class")[0];const rect = elem.getBoundingClientRect(); alert(rect.x + \":\" + rect.y)", "", 1);
```

And everything works great, but only "inside" javascript.

Here's the question: is it possible to somehow get the value of a variable to a rect.x to pull out and put in a C++ variable int rect_x ?

Comment: WebAssembly maybe?

Comment: @kiner_shah, no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might have noticed, if you type `rect.x` in the console in the developer tools, it echoes the variable value. It should have hinted you, how to retrieve variable values.

```cpp
CefRefPtr<CefV8Context> v8_context = frame->GetMainFrame()->GetV8Context();
if (v8_context.get() && v8_context->Enter()) {
  CefRefPtr<CefV8Value> retval;
  CefRefPtr<CefV8Exception> exception;
  if (v8_context->Eval("rect.x", "", 0, retval, exception)) {
    int rect_x = retval->GetIntValue()
  }
  v8_context->Exit();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Or maybe you can also tell me how to call a C++ callback from JS code? I didn't think right away, because js functions are executed asynchronously and I do not know at what point I need to check the value of the variable.

Comment: Thank you! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72999271/cef-how-to-call-callback-c-form-js-code